# Magento: Customer Account Create Form remove some Countries

Tags: magento, account

In the Customer Account Creation form I want to remove all other countries except Bangladesh.
That means I want to restrict customer registration process.

How can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this from your admin panel itself. Goto **Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Select Current configuration scope to Default config -> General -> countries option -> Allow countries** -> Choose allowed countries.

Thats it. You are done.